# Using CCMenuItemImage to create single buttons in the hud layer

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I just started a game using cocos2d-iphone and I am trying to add a pause botton in my hud.
My hud will have:

- Time left
- HP bar
- Pause button

I have been reading Ray Wenderlich's [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle) and he mentions for buttons `CCMenuItemImage` should be used. I first did:

```
CCMenuItemImage *pauseButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"hud_pause_bt.png" selectedImage:@"hud_pause_bt.png" target:self selector:@selector(pauseAction:)];
pauseButton.position = ccp(winSize.width - pauseButton.rect.size.width/1.8, winSize.height - pauseButton.rect.size.height/1.8);

[self addChild:pauseButton];
```

but I was never reaching the pauseAction method. Afterwards I tried adding the `CCMenuItemImage` to a `CCMenu` with the following code:

```
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

CCMenuItemImage *pauseButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"hud_pause_bt.png" selectedImage:@"hud_pause_bt.png" target:self selector:@selector(pauseAction:)];

pauseButton.position = ccp(winSize.width - pauseButton.rect.size.width/1.8, winSize.height - pauseButton.rect.size.height/1.8);

CCMenu *pauseMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pauseButton, nil];
pauseMenu.position = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:pauseMenu];
```

In this case the touches work but it feels wrong to create a `CCMenu` just to make my `CCMenuItemImage` clickable.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have done it is correct. That is the way CCMenu and CCMenuItems are designed to be used.

Consider just using a `CCStandardTouchDelegate` combined with `CGRectContainsPoint` if you don't like that method.